# Reading words and storing them into an array

Tags: c++

So I currently have a working programme which successfully finds and displays all the characters in an text file. I now want to be able to read whole words instead of characters and then want to store each word into an array but I have no idea how to even read whole words.

My current code for characters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("input.txt");

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: ";
        cout << "Can't open input file\n";
    }

    infile >> noskipws;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        char ch;
        infile >> ch;

        // Useful to check that the read isn't the end of file
        // - this stops an extra character being output at the end of the loop
        if (!infile.eof())
        {
            cout << ch << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Instead of `>>` into a `char` you can `>>` into a `std::string`

Comment: Please read the link about this statement: [`while (!infile.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

> I now want to be able to read whole words instead of characters and then want to store each word into an array but I have no idea how to even read whole words

```
std::string word;
infile >> word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `ch` to `std::string` so `>>` will read words.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
std::string word;
infile >> word;
```

Instead of,

```
char ch;
infile >> ch;
```